# How to merge statics for all instances of header-defined inline function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang, elf

Having a header that defines some `static inline` function that contains `static` variables in it, how to achieve merging of identical static local variables across all TUs that comprise final loadable module?. In a less abstract way:

```
/*
 * inc.h
 */
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 
 * This function must be provided via header. No extra .c source
 * is allowed for its definition.
 */
static inline void* getPtr() {
    static void* p;
    if (!p) {
        p = malloc(16);
    }
    return p;
}

/*
 * 1.c
 */
#include "inc.h"

void* foo1() {
    return getPtr();
}

void* bar1() {
    return getPtr();
}

/*
 * 2.c
 */
#include "inc.h"

void* foo2() {
    return getPtr();
}

void* bar2() {
    return getPtr();
}
```

Platform is Linux, and this file set is built via:

```
$ clang -O2 -fPIC -shared 1.c 2.c
```

It is quite expected that both TUs receive own copies of `getPtr.p`. Though inside each TU `getPtr.p` is shared across all `getPtr()` instantiations. This can be confirmed by inspecting final loadable binary:

```
$ readelf -s --wide a.out | grep getPtr
    32: 0000000000201030     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 getPtr.p
    34: 0000000000201038     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   21 getPtr.p
```

At the same time I'm looking for a way of how to share `getPtr.p` across separate TU boundary. This vaguely resembles what happens with C++ template instantiations. And likely `GRP_COMDAT` would help me but I was not able to find any info about how to label my static var to be put into COMDAT.

Is there any attribute or other source-level (not a compiler option) way to achieve merging such objects?

Comment: `identical static local variables across all TUs` - So.. can't you just move the definition to file scope and _merge_ the variables across all TUs by providing a single definition of a variable?

Comment: Why do you ask to have one instance of *getPtr* code and static variable in each file where you #include the header to after ask to have only one instance for all ? Because you want the function inline ?

Comment: @KamilCuk yup, that is an obviously correct way. I just forgot to underline that it is a requirement to have my function in header. You can consider it as a sort of "header-only library".

Comment: @bruno exuse me for being not clear enough. Definition must be put into header as I said in a comment above.

Comment: you cannot share the static variables but you can share the allocated memory not calling the *malloc* in each but using any way to get the same allocated buffer. The static variables do not use a lot of memory, this is different for the buffer whose can be large

Comment: @bruno I was using malloc() just to illustrate my problem, it is not an actual code. Rather my problem is how to guarantee that this internal function state can be kept in a single instance within my loadable module.

Comment: sergio, again you cannot share the static variables, but in a way there are not important, only their value is important isn't ? so share the variable value, not the variables themselves. If needed use a pointer to the value, for instance if the value must be an *int* then *p* is a static variable of type _int *_ and share that pointer to *int* and use _*p_ inside to have the same *int* in all cases

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can get this effect by simply declaring a global variable.

```c
/*
 * inc.h
 */

void* my_p;

static inline void* getPtr() {
    if (!my_p) {
        my_p = malloc(16);
    }
    return my_p;
}
```

This will use the same variable `my_p` for all instances of `getPtr` throughout the program (since it's global).  And it is not necessary to have an explicit definition of `my_p` in any module.  It will be initialized to `NULL`, which is just what you want.  So nothing besides `inc.h` needs to change, and no additional `.c` file is needed.

Of course, you'll probably want to give `my_p` a name that is less likely to conflict with any identifier in the user's program.  Maybe `Sergios_include_file_p_for_getPtr` or something of the sort.

This is actually an extension to standard C (mentioned in Annex J.5.11 in N2176), but it's provided by gcc and clang on most modern platforms.  It's documented under the `-fcommon` compiler option (which is enabled by default).  It's typically implemented by putting the variable in a `common` section, and the linker then merges all instances together, just as you suggest.  But the code above shows how to access the feature without needing to use attributes or other obscure incantations.

If you want to be extra paranoid, you can declare `my_p` with `__attribute__((common))` which will cause the variable to be treated in this way even if `-fno-common` is in effect.  (Of course, that may cause trouble if `-fno-common` was being used for a reason...)

Comment: Awesome! I totally forgot about these "unallocated externs". Yup, this works for me, though as you said with a some loss of data isolation. And it seems that compiler doesn't even put this to some section, rather it marks this object as an `SHN_COMMON`. Now linker is responsible for allocating a slot for it.

Comment: I've just found that unfortunately if header is included in cpp source it doesn't go so smooth. It allocates object in each TU, thus link step fails.

Comment: @Sergio: Maybe you want to ask a separate question about how to do this in C++, then.  I know less about that language.